# Vittoria Corsa 25 mm clincher on 14 mm rims

Tags: tire, rims

Currently I have 23 mm Continental tyres on my rims with 14 mm inner width.
I plan to buy Vittoria Corsa 25 mm clincher tyres.
Concerning clearance it should work out fine.
Is it safe and does it make sense to go for the 25 mm model with these rims or should I rather go for the 23 mm model?

Comment: Are they tubular rims?

Comment: Tubular rims never quote an "inner width" because there is no "inner." It sounds like you don't have tubular rims. Do not get tubular tires until you have tubular wheels (and make sure you know what you're getting into).

Comment: Could there be a confusion of terminology: Do you mean tube type clinchers, as opposed to tubeless or traditional tubular tyres?

Comment: I’m sorry. There is a confusion of terminology. I did mean tube type clinchers. I will edit the question.